# How to '$.all' a dynamic set of promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Let's say we have 3 promises and we pass them to $q.all. This will return a new promise that's resolved when the 3 promises are resolved.

Now if before the 3 promises are resolved I actually decide I want a 4th promise to be resolved as well, can this be done?

I tried something like:

```
var promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3];
var allDone = $q.all(promises);
promises.push(promise4);
```

In the above, `allDone` is resolved as soon as first 3 promises are resolved, but I would like it to wait for the 4th promise as well.

Or am I missing the point of promises here? Maybe I shouldn't be using promises for such cases?

**Update**: As answered, $q.all isn't capable of doing what I want. My question: Is there another way to know when a dynamic set of promises are resolved, so even when this set changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add promises to the array after the fact and expect it to influence the previous `.all()`.  That's not how `.all()` works.  You can, instead do this:

```
var promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3];
var allDone = $q.all(promises);

$q.all([allDone, promise4]).then(function() {
    // all four promises are done here
});
```

Or, you could just abandone the `allDone` promise and remake a new `.all()` like this:

```
var promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3];
var allDone = $q.all(promises);

promises.push(promise4);
var all4Done = $q.all(promises);
```

---

Based on your comments, here's another possibility.  Let's say the eventual done handler you want called is in a function named `allDoneNow()`.  Then, you could do something like this:

```
var promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3];
var allDone = $q.all(promises);
allDone.then(function(results) {
    // if no new promises have been added to the array
    if (promises.length === results.length) {
        // call our final handler
        return allDoneNow(results);
    } else {
        // wait for any new promises
        return $q.all(promises).then(allDoneNow);
    }
});

promises.push(promise4);
```

---

Or, if you want it recursive so it keeps checking for more, you can put it in a function like this that can be used recursively:

```
function waitAll(promiseArray) {
    return $q.all(promiseArray).then(function(results) {
        if (promiseArray.length <= results.length) {
            // everything currently in the promiseArray is now done
            return results;
        } else {
            // there are some new things in the promiseArray so
            // wait until they are done
            return waitAll(promiseArray);
        }
    });
}


var promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3];
waitAll(promises).then(function(results) {
    // all promises currently in the promises array are done
});

promises.push(promise4);
```

Comment: Hmm, but this would require me to somehow cancel any .then() callback attached to the first $q.all. I was hoping for a simpler solution :-).

Comment: @user125661 -  You've registered a handler for the completion of three promises.  You can't change that.  You can add new handlers that will notify you of newly created conditions.  If, when you have the first three promises, you're aware that you might have more promises BEFORE the first three are done, then don't register the final handler yet.  Register a dummy handler whose job it is to check if there are any more promises you also need to wait on and if not, then it can call the handler.

Comment: that makes sense! Another solution I figured might be to add a dummy promise to the set of four promises. As soon as I know the original set of promises should be changes, I can reject that dummy promise, and setup a new $q.all as you suggested above.

Comment: @user125661 - I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Nice. I would suggest to name the dummyHandler, and then change `return $q.all(promises).then(allDoneNow);` to `return $q.all(promises).then(dummyHandler);` to make it recursive. You can keep checking for changes that way for as long as necessary.

Comment: @user125661 - Yeah, I wondered if you wanted it recursive - wasn't sure if you needed that or not.  But, it sounds like you've got the general idea now.

Comment: @user125661 - I added a recursive implementation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can check the source code of [$q all()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L540) function, you will see that it just travels all promises with forEach() and return another promise which will resolve all result later on.

So if you push another promise into the array it does not effect it at all, as it already sets all promises and done with your promises array.

Comment: Thanks! I guess my actual question is: is there a way in which I could get such behavior?